# Derivation of why a diagonalizable matrix can be written as a sum of outer products $\Sigma=\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i v_i v_i^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

Lets say we have a symmetric positive semi-definite $n\times n$ matrix $\Sigma$, which therefore has a diagonalization $\Sigma=V\Lambda V^T$, where $V$ is an orthogonal matrix (containing the eigenvectors $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ of $\Sigma$) and $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix (containing the eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n$ of $\Sigma$).

Could you show me how the following sum of outer products is derived?

$$\Sigma=\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_iv_iv_i^T$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It helps to have internalized the following ways of looking at matrix multiplication:

- $Ax = a_1 x_1 + \cdots + a_n x_n$, where $a_i$ is the $i$th column of the matrix $A$ and $x_i$ is the $i$th component of the vector $x$.
- $A \begin{bmatrix} b_1 & \cdots & b_n \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} A b_1 & \cdots & A b_n \end{bmatrix}$, where $b_i$ is the $i$th column of the matrix $B$.
- $\begin{bmatrix} a_1 & \cdots & a_n \end{bmatrix} 
  \begin{bmatrix} b_1^T \\ \vdots \\ b_n^T \end{bmatrix}
  = a_1 b_1^T + \cdots + a_n b_n^T$.  Here the vector $a_i$ is the $i$th column of $A$ and the row vector $b_i^T$ is the $i$th row of $B$.

You can use rules 2 and 1 to compute $V \Lambda$, and then use rule 3 to compute $V \Lambda V^T$.

Alternatively, you can think of it like this.  The matrix $v_i v_i^T$ projects a vector $x$ onto the span of $\{ v_i \}$.  This projection then gets scaled by $\lambda_i$.  In other words:
\begin{equation}
x = \sum_{i=1}^n v_i v_i^T x
\end{equation}
so
\begin{align}
\Sigma x &= \sum_{i=1}^n \Sigma v_i v_i^T x \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i v_i v_i^T x.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you very much! I've actually never thought of rule 3 - that one clarified everything for me.

Comment: Sure. Gilbert Strang emphasizes rule 3 (as well as the other viewpoints) in his linear algebra books.

Comment: Indeed his book is great. Unfortunately, I only only discovered it four days before my exam, so I only read selected chapters (which were great tough). I wish I had discovered his book before.